# How to access LVM partitions on OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, lvm, osx-snow-leopard, data-recovery

I need to access ext3 partitions over an LVM logical volume in a SATA HD connected through USB2 to my iMac with OS X 10.6 .

**Is it possible to see LVM volumes from OS X? How?**

Disk Utility says that the attached device is unknown and propose to initialize it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, they can.  see this article… [Mac OS X Lion Adds CoreStorage, a Volume Manager (Finally!)](http://blog.fosketts.net/2011/08/04/mac-osx-lion-corestorage-volume-manager/)

> What is a volume manager? Volume managers add flexibility to operating
>   system allocation of storage, acting as a virtualization layer between
>   disks and file systems. This is important, since modern computer
>   systems need to maintain a consistent filesystem image even as storage
>   devices change. Volume managers like Symantec’s Veritas Volume Manager
>   and the OSF LVM allow many operating systems this sort of flexible
>   storage management. But Apple never had a volume manager of their own
>   until the introduction of CoreStorage in Mac OS X “Lion”. Read more at
>   [Volume Management: Virtualizing Host Storage.](http://blog.fosketts.net/2008/02/21/volume-management-virtualizing-host-storage/)

Comment: +1 for the update ... BTW Core Storage is quite a young tool for now, as a proof you can take the high number of undocumented commands it has ... Nevertheless it is working for the scope of this topic :)

Comment: I thought the question was asking how to access Linux [tag:lvm] volumes from OS X. There are 2 other answers that do address this.

Comment: I agree with RichVel, this does not address the question at all.

Comment: @mralexgray Is Macos's CoreStorage able to "see" LVM LVs ?

Answer (score 6):

OS X Cannot read an LVM Volume, and there are no 3rd party drivers at the moment (or that I'm aware of) to do so. The easiest solution would be to boot off a linux live cd (Ubuntu etc) on your imac, mount the drive, and copy the data elsewhere.

You could also maybe try installing a Linux virtual machine using one of many 3rd party products (VMware Fusion, Parallels, Virtual Box), and mount the volume in there.

Comment: I already have tried to transfer all data I need using a REHL5 over Vmware Fusion. But, since I need to transfer over 50Gb of data, I repeatedly have gone against a _total machine hang_, it seems that massive I/0 is not supported very well in OS X/Fusion/USB.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem... to address this issue I created a Mac OS X kernel extension which maps simple Linux LVM layouts to logical partitions in Mac OS X:
https://github.com/unsound/IOLVMPartitionScheme

It's available under an open source license (LGPLv2.1). It's not a complete volume manager, obviously, so only single-disk LVM layouts can be expected to work, and only non-snapshot volumes, etc. but should be good enough for most automatically created LVM layouts for the boot drive.

You still have to find a way to mount the ext3 volume though... [fuse-ext2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/) should do the trick.

Edit: More info, including a binary, is available on [my blog](http://catacombae.blogspot.se/2014/04/iolvmpartitionscheme-using-simple-linux.html).

Comment: very good work :)

Answer (score 4):

The `diskutil cs list` command is what you're looking for. Try that at the terminal. Then type `diskutil cs` for a short list of CoreStorage commands you can use. [I wrote more about it on my blog here](http://blog.fosketts.net/2012/10/03/mac-os-corestorage-tricks/):.

Comment: Was hoping to use a built-in but it does not recognize the LVM image as the second partition in the VMDK file I have used with my VirtualBox VM that I had loaded with the Paragon VMDK Mounter as a CoreStorage disk and refuses to work list it.

Answer (score 2):

I went with [Ryan's solution](https://serverfault.com/a/66950/191935) and it worked. Note that using a virtual machine for data transfer will be **slower** than booting directly into a live cd. Here's a more in detail how to:

Assuming your disk is on a **usb device**:

1. Grab [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with `extension-pack` (usually works better)
   Example using [brew](https://brew.sh/) and [brew cask](https://caskroom.github.io/):

   brew cask install virtualbox virtualbox-extension-pack
2. Download a [virtualbox ubuntu image](https://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/) (could be an other distro too btw, i used `Ubuntu Linux 15.04 x86_64` with password `reverse`)
3. Configure a shared folder from the settings (optional, do this only if you want to copy data from disk to your mac)
4. `Enable USB Controller` from `Ports` settings (I used `USB 3.0 (xHCI) controller`)

   [image: virtualbox-ports-usb-settings]
5. Start the vm
6. Insert guest cd from virtualbox menu `devices > Insert guest cd image` and install it, (I did this, but I don't know if it was necessary for usb support).
7. Open a terminal in ubuntu and install `lvm2`

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install -y lvm2
   ```
8. Make sure all disks from the usb device are ejected on your mac side
9. Click the usb icon bottom right (Mine was a seagate, don't judge me) :P

   [image: virtualbox usb icon bottom right menu]

If things went well, you should see your lvm volume(s) in the sidebar of the ubuntu's file browser (Nautilus). It should automount into `/media/ubuntu/<name_of_lvm_volume>`

Otherwise, you may have to follow [How to mount lvm partition on ubuntu](https://quonn.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/how-to-mount-lvm-partition-on-ubuntu/).

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I used parallels 4.0 running rhel 5.5 and was able to mount the linux lvm using the standard mount commands for lvm (e.g. mount /dev/VolGroup/LogVol00 /mnt/usb ).  also, these may be of use to you as well:

`pvs`

`lvdisplay /dev/VolGroup`

`vgchange -ay`

I needed to mark the volume as available as lvdisplay was showing it as NOT available.